they are a kind of time machine, so real~

The most surreal consequence of melting ice and rising seas is that together they are a kind of time machine, so real that they are altering the length of our days. It works like this: As the glaciers melt and the seas rise, gravity forces more water toward the equator. This changes the shape of the Earth ever so slightly, making it fatter around the middle, which in turns slows the rotation of the planet similarly to the way a ballet dancer slows her spin by spreading out her arms.

(from The Water Will Come by Jeff Goodell)
Which is 'so real'? In terms of meaning, which is the subject of 'so real'? I am confused.

(the fact that) together they are a kind of time machine
a kind of time machine
time machine

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

The words so real appear to be a play on words with the earlier word surreal. The time machine is so real that it has a real effect - the melting ice and rising seas alter the length of our days.

This is also an implicit allusion to the contrast with the more usual meaning of "time machine," a device which allows one to travel through time.  Such time machines are fictional, therefore unreal.

I thought it was going to raise the even more surreal point that moving any mass from the poles to the equator also causes the earth itself to become fractionally "wider" over and above raising equatorial sea levels. Consequently, time really does pass slightly faster because of relativity, for people who live near the equator rather than the poles. It's already an issue for technology that communications, geolocation, etc. have to take account of: Time on the moon passes about 56–58.7 microseconds faster each day than on Earth.


The most surreal consequence of melting ice and rising seas is that together they are a kind of time machine, so real that they are altering the length of our days.

To understand this, you have to apply context and some knowledge and common sense, rather than linguistic guidance.
"a kind of time machine" does not mean "a machine that enables travel through time"; it means "a machine that alters time."
We know this because between one and two billion years ago, a day on earth lasted only 19 hours. Since that time, The earth's rotation has been slowing and now it takes, as you know, 24 hours for a complete rotation.
The article tells us that eventually the time taken for the earth to complete one rotation will be even longer.

The most surreal consequence of melting ice and rising seas is that together they are a kind of time machine, so real that they are altering the length of our days.

=

The most surreal consequence of melting ice and rising seas is that together they are a kind of time machine, the effects of which are so real that they (their effects) are altering the length of our days.


The machine does not alter time, strickly speaking; it merely alters the length of the day: more of the same time is counted for the length of any given day. // Your correction corresponds exactly to the idea I had: that of a slack phrasing that could be improved, the very term "effect" being in my mind what "so real" would properly  qualify. However, because of the vague reference as to what "so real" qualifies in the initial sentence, I do not feel that this sentence should be a mere equivalent.


".., so real that they are altering the length of our days."

It would be rewritten: "It is so real that they are altering the length of our days."
So what is so real? The fact that they are altering the length of our days is so real.
